# Undefined Reference Error/ Dynamically Calling Functions

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic, undefined-reference

Hi I am working on a program that involves a Main.cpp, Connect4.cpp, and Connect4.h file. When I compile my program I am getting an error in the Main file saying that my playGame function is an undefined reference. I am compiling both files together(main first) I believe something is wrong in the way I am trying to dynamically call the function playGame. Any input would be much appreciated!

> Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include "Connect4.h"
void playGame();

using namespace std;

int main()
{
Connect4 *ptr;
ptr=new Connect4;
ptr-> playGame();
delete ptr;
}
```

> Connect4.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include "Connect4.h"

char gameBoard[9][7];
int rows;
int columns;

using namespace std;
void playGame()
{
void display();
int selectColumn(bool);
int tokenPlacement(char token, int columns);
bool winOrLose();
cout<<"Welcome to Connect Four.";
for(int i=0; i<rows;++i)
{
    for(int j=0; j<columns; ++j)
    {
        gameBoard[i][j]=' ';
    }
}
bool player1Turn=true;
char winner='n';
int column =0;
while(true){
    display();

    column=selectColumn(player1Turn);

    if(player1Turn==true)
    {
        tokenPlacement('x',column);
        player1Turn=false;
    }
    else
    {
        tokenPlacement('o', column);
        player1Turn=true;

    winner= winOrLose();
    if(winner!='n')
    {
        break;
    }
}
cout<<"Winner is:"<<winner;

   }
```

> Connect4.h
>       #ifndef CONNECT4_H_
>       #define CONNECT4_H_
>       #include 
>       using namespace std;

```
class Connect4 {
public:
static void playGame();

private:
void display();
int selectColumn(bool);
int tokenPlacement(char, int);
bool winOrLose();
char gameBoard[9][7];


};

#endif /* CONNECT4_H_ */
```

Comment: If you actually read the error message, you will see that it's not `playGame()` that it's not defined. Once you wrap your brain around the name of the actual function that's not defined, you should be able to figure this out by yourself.

Comment: How are you compiling the code? Also, there is no need to create things using `new` as you are doing - this is C++ not Java.

Comment: I am compiling by g++ -c Main.cpp Connect4.cpp in my school's UNIX server

Comment: your code of `Connect4.cpp` wrong. you need not `void playGame(){}` but `void Connect4::playGame(){}` `char gameBoard[9][7];` this is what ?!? class memer or global variable ?

Comment: My problem was how I was implementing playGame() in Connect4.cpp thank you for the fix RbMm!

Comment: B.Cooney: Recommend that you address Neil Butterworth's comment. The code in `main` demonstrates that you are not grasping several fundamental C++ concepts. Maybe you are falling back on knowledge of another language, maybe not; regardless you're in for a few surprises. For example, do you know which `gameBoard` variable `playGame `is using? There are two.